# What is the difference between 「何を...ましょうか」, 「何を...ますか」 and 「何を...ませんか」?

Tags: usage, questions

1. What are the differences in meaning between these three sentences?

   > えいがはなにを**みましょう**か。
   >   えいがはなにを**みます**か。
   >   えいがはなにを**みません**か。
2. Does the last sentence even make sense?

Answer (score 3):

えいがはなにをみましょうか implies an invitation. しましょう(か) means "Let's". It means (私達は)何の映画をみようか("What movie should we watch?" Or "Let's watch a movie. What is a good movie to watch?"),

えいがはなにをみますか is a question. It is "What movies do you watch?"

えいがはなにをみませんか is also a question. You are asking someone what movies he doesn't watch. However, it is rarely used and a bit unnatural. I say どんな映画は見ないのですか.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer first your 2nd question, and after that I will address your 1st question.

---

### **2. Does the last sentence even make sense?**

No, the 3rd sentence does not make sense. Only the 1st and the 2nd sentences make sense:

> えいがはなにをみますか。Regarding movies, what will [you/we] watch?
>
> えいがはなにをみましょうか。Regarding movies, shall we [you/we] watch?

Using ません or ましょうか turns the question more into a proposal:

> ラーメンを食【た】べ**ませんか**。Won't [you/we] eat ramen?
>   ラーメンを食【た】べ**ましょう**。Let's eat ramen.

It does not make sense:

> <s>えいがはなにをみ**ませんか**。Regarding movies, what movie won't [you/we] watch?</s>

To propose the listener to watch a movie with ませんか or ましょうか, you can also use:

1. なにか (it means "something"), and drop を:

   > えいがは**なにか**みませんか。Regarding movies, won't [you/we] watch some [movie]?
   >   えいがは**なにか**みましょうか。Regarding movies, Let's watch some [movie]?
2. The actual title of the movie:

   > えいがは**Star Wars**をみませんか。Regarding movies, won't [you/we] watch Star Wars?
   >   えいがは**Star Wars**をみましょうか。Regarding movies, Let's watch Star Wars?
3. Remove えいがは and use えいが as the object of 見【み】る directly:

   > えいがをみませんか。Won't [you/we] watch Star Wars?
   >   えいがをみましょうか。Let's watch Star Wars?

---

### 1. What are the differences in meaning between these three sentences?

If you compare the three sentences used as a proposal (as explained in the previous section), **they mean the same, but the difference is in the *level of politeness* of each proposal**. In the Japanese language, in general, the *less* direct you are the *more* polite you sound. So, arranged from the *more* polite to the *less* polite:

> 1) えいがは**なにか**みませんか。Regarding movies, won't [you/we] watch some [movie]?
>   2) えいがは**なにか**みましょうか。Regarding movies, let's watch some [movie]?.
>   3) えいがは**なにか**みますか。Regarding movies, will [you/we] watch some [movie]?.

(1)(ませんか) is a *negative* sentence and therefore it is the most *indirect*. For this reason, it is the politest one.

(3)(ますか) is a *positive* sentence and therefore it is the most *direct*. For this reason, it is the less polite. To be honest, I don't think it is frequently used to make a proposal because it sounds too direct. I guess it is more used as a regular question.

(2)(ましょうか) is somewhat in the middle. ましょう is the standard grammar to make proposals in Japanese. Worth noting that if you don't add the か to ましょう, it is still valid as a proposal sentence, but ましょうか is politer than ましょう because, again, turning it a question by adding か makes it more indirect and therefore, politer. So, adding ましょう to the comparison, from the **more** polite to the **less** polite:

> 1) えいがは**なにか**みませんか。Regarding movies, won't [you/we] watch some [movie]?
>   2) えいがは**なにか**みましょうか。Regarding movies, let's watch some [movie]?.
>   3) えいがは**なにか**みましょう。Regarding movies, let's watch some [movie].
>   4) えいがは**なにか**みますか。Regarding movies, will [you/we] watch some [movie]?.

Comment: 「えいがはなにをみましょうか。」は、"What movie shall we watch?" って意味で使いますね。

Comment: そうですか。じゃ、答えを直します。「えいがはなにをみませんか」というのは言えますか。

Comment: 「えいがはなにをみませんか。」は、ちょっと変ですね。（「見ない・嫌いな映画（のジャンル）は特にありますか・何ですか」って意味かな？と思いますけど。）... あと、「えいが**は**なに**か**みましょうか。」より、「えいが**を**なに**か**みましょうか。(≂なにかえいがをみましょうか。)」って言うような気もしますね・・・